# How do I display a Line Graph in Xamarin.Forms that can show detail popups and horizontal lines for thresholds on IOS and Android?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, graph, xamarin.forms

How do I display a Line Graph in Xamarin.Forms that can show:

1. detail popups (when you press a data point, more info comes up for it such as date and time and it's numeric value for instance)
2. horizontal lines for thresholds (similar to [Show a threshold line in Flex Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826094/show-a-threshold-line-in-flex-chart) but for Xamarin).

I've looked at [Graphing for Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988949/graphing-for-xamarin-forms) and haven't found exactly what I'm looking for yet. Note: I'm using https://github.com/aloisdeniel/Microcharts at the moment.

Must be Free and I prefer open-source. If there's no way to do it, how to make a custom renderer either over top of MicroCharts (what I'm using now) or from scratch? Would SkiaSharp work for this purpose as it's a 2d drawing library/framework? Also MUST work on both IOS and Android.

Comment: [SkiaSharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/) would probably work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steema Teechart .net is the only library that works thus far. For those interested, go to https://www.steema.com/product/net.

and it's documentation, though not complete: http://wiki.teechart.net/index.php?title=TeeChart_for_NET

Answer (score 0):

You could do a workaround like that by doing the process in code behind by using Boxview and tweaking the heightrequest. as for your example you could do some thing like this:

```
<StackLayout>
<BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Red" Margin="0,-100,0,0"> //Red Line
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="BarGraph"/>
</StackLayout>
```

in the code behind to create the bar graph:

1. Create an array of stack layout and then loop the array
2. now inside the loop add green box view to each array of stack, and
   add an additional red if it is greater than 350. dont forget to set the heightrequest of each boxview
3. Then add them in the BarGraph StackLayout

and also the Boxview(Red line in the comment) playaround with the value with negative to bring it down inline with the bargraph .

Answer (score 0):

Try Oxyplot https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/

Here are the docs http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/models/index.html

It is opensource. you can create a complex graph with this library. hope it helps.

here is a sample with LineSeries.

```
    var model = new PlotModel("LineSeries") { LegendSymbolLength = 24 };
    var s1 = new LineSeries("Series 1")
    {
        Color = OxyColors.SkyBlue,
        MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle,
        MarkerSize = 6,
        MarkerStroke = OxyColors.White,
        MarkerFill = OxyColors.SkyBlue,
        MarkerStrokeThickness = 1.5
    };
    s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 10));
    s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(10, 40));
    s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(40, 20));
    s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(60, 30));
    model.Series.Add(s1);
```

you can create any number of series you want and keep adding it to the `model.Series`

Comment: Documentation for it is VERY poor for xamarin.forms, and I have not been able to get it to display anything.

Comment: Even the official examples don't work... dissappointing. i'll have to figure something out with microcharts i guess.

Answer (score 0):

[SkiaChart](https://github.com/NdubuisiJr/skia-chart) is free, flexible, easy to use, and yes it is open source too.